# how to convert a RGB color value to an hexadecimal value in C++?

Tags: c++, hex, rgb

In my C++ application, I have a png image's color in terms of Red, Green, Blue values. I have stored these values in three integers.

How to convert RGB values into the equivalent hexadecimal value?

Example of that like in this format 0x1906

EDIT: I will save the format as GLuint.

Comment: In that number, `0x1906`, which bits represents the different colors?

Comment: I am not sure about it. But it should be like RGB sequence! Dont know if it answers your question. Sorry!

Comment: Wait, you want to convert to some format but you don't know what that format is? There is only one way to solve that problem, and no one can really help you with that.

Comment: The format should be as like as the format of GL_ALPHA. Which is equal to 0x1906. It is defined on GLES.

Comment: Well, it would help lots if you explained that in the question. It would avoid the need for people to look up the GLES spec in order to answer.

Comment: I have looked it up and the GL_ALPHA format involves only one component: the *alpha* value. **There is no red; there is no green; there is no blue; there is no spoon.** This question is very very unclear.

Comment: I understand. I explained my problem in unwind's answer as a comment. Thanks.

Comment: Um... What is meant by "hexadecimal value" in this question? Are you talking about an ASCII string representing the value in hex notation?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Store the appropriate bits of each color into an unsigned integer of at least 24 bits (like a `long`):

```
unsigned long createRGB(int r, int g, int b)
{   
    return ((r & 0xff) << 16) + ((g & 0xff) << 8) + (b & 0xff);
}
```

Now instead of:

```
unsigned long rgb = 0xFA09CA;
```

you can do:

```
unsigned long rgb = createRGB(0xFA, 0x09, 0xCA);
```

Note that the above will not deal with the alpha channel.  If you need to also encode alpha (RGBA), then you need this instead:

```
unsigned long createRGBA(int r, int g, int b, int a)
{   
    return ((r & 0xff) << 24) + ((g & 0xff) << 16) + ((b & 0xff) << 8)
           + (a & 0xff);
}
```

Replace `unsigned long` with `GLuint` if that's what you need.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to build a string, you can probably use `snprintf()`:

```
const unsigned red = 0, green = 0x19, blue = 0x06;
char hexcol[16];

snprintf(hexcol, sizeof hexcol, "%02x%02x%02x", red, green, blue);
```

This will build the string `001906" in`hexcol`, which is how I chose to interpret your example color (which is only four digits when it should be six).

You seem to be confused over the fact that the `GL_ALPHA` preprocessor symbol is defined to be `0x1906` in OpenGL's header files. This is not a color, it's a *format specifier* used with OpenGL API calls that deal with pixels, so they know what format to expect.

If you have a PNG image in memory, the `GL_ALPHA` format would correspond to *only* the alpha values in the image (if present), the above is something totally different since it builds a string. OpenGL won't need a string, it will need an in-memory buffer holding the data in the format required.

See the `glTexImage2D()` manual page for a discussion on how this works.

Comment: You got my problem exactly right. This is where I got stuck. I have the rgb values I got from the PLTE chunk of a png image. I want to set the texture format. But the image's color type is 3 which is an indexed color. Normally for other color type like 0 (PNG_COLOR_TYPE_GRAY) i set the texture format as 0x1909 (GL_LUMINANCE). But what should I do for color type 3? I have made a  post about it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373099/png-image-texture-format-for-color-type-3