# OpenCV concatenate 3 channels to 32-bit value?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am looking for the fastest way of converting 3 channels RGB frame to 1 channel picture in openCV. But I need to concatenate all three colors (R, G, B) of the pixel into one 32-bit value.

Every pixel should consist for an example:

> pixel[0:31]= 01001001 11110000 11111111 00000000

The first 8 bits are RED color from the frame (at the same position in frame), second 8 bits are from green color and third 8 bits are from blue, last 8 bits are not important.

I tried this:

```
for (y = 100; y < 500; y++){
     for (x = 100; x < 500; x++) {
        int pixel =((edges.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[0])<<16)|
                    ((edges.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[1])<<8)|
                    (edges.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[2]);
}}
```

But this is to slow, because I need to go through every pixel in the frame.

Thanks

Comment: I'm going to guess that opencv internally stores the data in the format you are looking for... have you done a `&edges.at(y, x)[ compare address of all 3 values here? ]` to see where their addresses are? If you tell opencv to store them as a 32-bit value (8 bits per channel with an alpha value) you might be able to do a whole-sale memcpy from the data pointer in the opencv Mat.

Comment: - sorry quick answer was a placeholder until I found the links to the online docs. We might want to not be quite so quick to moderate answers

Comment: I agree with @RyanP, but don't know if it's the fastest way (don't have time to test it right now). However, you can speed up your code simply saving a const reference to a Vec3b,and using at<> just once per loop. Or even better use raw pointers. I'll add a complete answer asap.

Comment: Also, you'll get a good speedup inverting for loops, i.e. first on rows, second on colums

Comment: @RyanP on second toughts, you should **never** do a memcpy, unless you are sure that matrix IsContinuous, or you get undesired results due to matrix padding (step)

Comment: Thank you all for  quick responses. @RyanP this is nice idea, I'll try it. I am taking frames from web camera and then I need to convert frame to  the format above. After that, I need  to copy frame to the /dev/fb0 (framebuffer sends frames to VGA display), so it needs to be fast.

Comment: shouldnt it be `((edges.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[0])<<24)|
                    ((edges.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[1])<<16)|
                    ((edges.at<Vec3b>(y, x)[2])<<8)` ??

Comment: @Micka It all depends how you setup your framebuffer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried some variants:

- **Method 0a** : as in the question, @Sveva
- **Method 0b** : as in the question, with for loops inverted, @Miki
- **Method 1**  : querying value from mat only once using indices, @Miki
- **Method 2**  : querying value from mat using pointers, @Miki
- **Method 3**  : converting to BGRA and `memcpy`, @RyanP NOTE: works only if mat `isContinuos()`.

**Results** (time in milliseconds)

```
isContinuos? 1
Method 0a: 113.704              0x1020300
Method 0b: 20.0975              0x1020300
Method 1: 20.1939               0x1020300
Method 2: 15.7434               0x1020300
Method 3: 22.5592               0xff030201
```

**Considerations**

Inverting the for loops has a major speedup, because OpenCV `Mat` are row-major ordered.
**The fastest method is Method 2, using pointers.** Method 1 is slightly slower, but probably more readable. 
Method 3 is quite fast, but a single `memcpy` works only if the matrix `isContinuos()`. If not the case, you need to loop on each row, and `memcpy` each row, and this is going to be (only a little) slower.

**NOTE**

OpenCV stores BGR values (not RGB). Methods 0a, 0b, 1 and 2 output the values as: `B G R 0`. You just need to swap the index 0 and 2 to get `R G B 0`. For Method 3, you need to use `cvtColor` with parameter `COLOR_BGR2RGBA`.

**Code**

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Test Image
    Mat3b img(2000, 3000, Vec3b(1, 2, 3));
    cout << "isContinuos? " << img.isContinuous() << endl;

    // Method 0a: method from question. Credits to @Sveto
    double tic0a = double(getTickCount());
    vector<int> v0a(img.rows * img.cols, 0);
    for (int c = 0; c < img.cols; ++c)
    {
        for (int r = 0; r < img.rows; ++r)
        {
            v0a[r*img.cols + c] = ((img.at<Vec3b>(r, c)[0]) << 24) |
                ((img.at<Vec3b>(r, c)[1]) << 16) |
                (img.at<Vec3b>(r, c)[2]) << 8;
        }
    }
    double toc0a = (double(getTickCount()) - tic0a) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Method 0a: " << toc0a << "\t\t";;
    cout << "0x" << hex << v0a[0] << endl;

    // Method 0b: method from question, loops inverted
    double tic0b = double(getTickCount());
    vector<int> v0b(img.rows * img.cols, 0);
    for (int r = 0; r < img.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < img.cols; ++c)
        {
            v0b[r*img.cols + c] = ((img.at<Vec3b>(r, c)[0]) << 24) |
                ((img.at<Vec3b>(r, c)[1]) << 16) |
                (img.at<Vec3b>(r, c)[2]) << 8;
        }
    }
    double toc0b = (double(getTickCount()) - tic0b) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Method 0b: " << toc0b << "\t\t";
    cout << "0x" << hex << v0b[0] << endl;


    // Method 1: custom loop with indices
    double tic1 = double(getTickCount());
    vector<int> v1(img.rows * img.cols, 0);
    for (int r = 0; r < img.rows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < img.cols; ++c)
        {
            const Vec3b& b = img(r, c);
            v1[r*img.cols + c] = (b[0] << 24) | (b[1] << 16) | (b[2] << 8);
        }
    }
    double toc1 = (double(getTickCount()) - tic1) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Method 1: " << toc1 << "\t\t";
    cout << "0x" << hex << v1[0] << endl;

    // Method 2: custom loop with pointers
    double tic2 = double(getTickCount());
    vector<int> v2(img.rows * img.cols, 0);
    for (int r = 0; r < img.rows; ++r)
    {
        uchar* p = img.ptr<uchar>(r);
        for (int c = 0; c < img.cols; ++c)
        {
            int val = ((*p) << 24); ++p;
            val |= ((*p) << 16); ++p;
            val |= ((*p) << 8); ++p;
            v2[r*img.cols + c] = val;
        }
    }
    double toc2 = (double(getTickCount()) - tic2) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Method 2: " << toc2 << "\t\t";
    cout << "0x" << hex << v2[0] << endl;


    // Method 3: using BGRA conversion. Credits @RyanP
    // NOTE: works only if img.isContinuos()
    double tic3 = double(getTickCount());
    Mat4b rgba3;
    cvtColor(img, rgba3, COLOR_BGR2BGRA);
    vector<int> v3(img.rows * img.cols, 0);
    memcpy(v3.data(), rgba3.data, img.rows * img.cols * sizeof(int));

    double toc3 = (double(getTickCount()) - tic3) * 1000. / getTickFrequency();
    cout << "Method 3: " << toc3 << "\t\t";
    cout << "0x" << hex << v3[0] << endl;

    int dummy;
    cin >> dummy;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks a lot @Miki.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [split](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=split) and [merge](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=merge) channels functions.

The look complicated but are a lot easier than doing it a pixel at a time.

See stackoverflow.com/questions/14582082/merging-channels-in-opencv for sample

Comment: The result of doing a split and a merge should be to take interleaved data, split it out into 3 different channels, and then interleave it again... He might want to verify that the data he has isn't already what he needs. If he's storing it in a Mat that is of type 8UC4, and the channels are in the correct order that he needs them in, he already has what he needs, he just needs to memcpy the data from the cv::Mat data pointer.

Comment: @RyanP - I read it that he had an RGB image and  needed to pad it to an RGBA (with the A ignored). There is no way to do this without a lot of copy but at least the split/merge will do it efficently

Comment: True he might have to do that. However, if he has the ability to change his code to use an 8UC4 data type (assuming he doesn't already) instead of 8UC3 it might be easier/faster to change it to do so and memcpy instead of split and merge. Though the author needs to pipe up and say what he has and what he can do to answer that.